# How to grab Facebook access_token via GET in URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I was redirected from the OAuth Dialog, my application URL looks like this.

```
login/auth_fb/#access_token=AAAB
```

How can I grab my access_token from the URL? If it is

```
login/auth_fb/?access_token=AAAB
```

In CodeIgniter, I can get it easily like $this->input->get('access_token',TRUE);

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That part of the url is called the hash. BUT you can't get it from the server side - what you need to do is write some javascript to grab it on the client and pass it back in on a POST.

Comment: is there any way I can get the access_token without passing through POST?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware - the hash part of the url seems to get lost on a server.